# How does this trigonometric simplifier work?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I recently watched this video of Wolfram channel about modelling black holes with Mathematica. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOtvvw1dyN0 At 13:45

In it, they have created a trigonometric simplifier, which simplifies trigonometric expressions even when Mathematica's built-in functions don't work. The code is visible in the video, and i have posted it here.

I have tried to understand how it works, but with only few months of using Mathematica, I can't really understand how it works. Can any of you explain more in depth what this piece of code is actually doing?

```
$TrigFns = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot};
(WRules = $TrigFns == (Through[$TrigFns[x]] /. x -> 2 ArcTan[t] // 
    TrigExpand // Together) // Thread);

invWRules = #[[1]] -> Solve[#, t, Reals] & /@ WRules;

convert[expr_, (trig : Alternatives @@ $TrigFns)[x_]] :=
Block[{temp, t}, 
temp = expr /. x -> 2 ArcTan[t] // TrigExpand // Factor; 
  temp = temp /. (trig /. invWRules) // Union // FullSimplify; 
  Or @@ temp /. trig -> HoldForm[trig][x] /. 
    ConditionalExpression -> (#1 &) // FullSimplify]
```

Now running for example
`convert[Sin[x]^2 - Cos[3 x], Cos[x]]` yields `1-Cos[x](-3+Cos[x]+4Cos[x]^2)`

Comment: Seems to use the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). Have you tried contacting the person who wrote this?

Comment: Search this site for "Weierstrass substitution"